# Plot curves instead of bar plot using python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scipy, seaborn

I have a dataframe `df` that I use to produce two bar plots on the same x-axis. Instead of displaying these values as bar plots, I'd like a curve that fits the shape of the bars. I.e. it should sort of be like a gaussian or normal distribution fit, but I want to keep the x-axis and y-axis the same, and not show frequency. I also need the fit to start at 0 and be for any negative values. How can I do this? I imagine the scipy `curve_fit` function might be useful or `sns.distplot`?

```
df
    size    a           b
    0       0.000000    6.20405
    1       0.000000    9.262046
    2       2.51524     14.28944
    3       6.750392    12.756672
    4       9.893210    9.733124
    5       10.302983   6.690388
    6       11.302383   4.86942
    7       8.024279    8.32051
    8       4.39434     7.228450
    9       2.05516     3.767661

x = df['a']
y = df['b']

n = 10

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

bar_width = 0.4  # default: 0.8
bar_locations = np.arange(n)

ax.bar(bar_locations, x, bar_width)
ax.bar(bar_locations - bar_width, y, bar_width, color='r') 

fig.show()
```

**Update:**

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for a in [x, y]:
    sns.distplot(a, bins=range(1, 25, 1), ax=ax, kde=True, fit=stats.gamma)
```

How do I clean this figure to a) force the kde fit to not be for any negative numbers (the data start at 0!) and b) remove the black lines and green/blue bars?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just need `sns.distplot` with `kde=True`. This shows the kernel density estimator as a frequency curve. Your manual bar plots will obscure the curve due to the difference in scale however, so you should plot them on a secondary y axis or rescale them if they are needed.

Alternatively `sns.kdeplot` plots only the KDE curve without the histogram bars.

## Update

Try this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for a in [x, y]:
    sns.distplot(
        a, bins=range(1, 25, 1), ax=ax,
        kde=True, hist=False, fit=None)
```

It is not really clear what sort of curve fit you want, but read [the docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html#seaborn.distplot) for `distplot`. `kde=True` adds KDE curves, `hist=True` adds bars, `fit=stats.gamma` fits a gamma distribution (shown as a black line).

As for removing negative values, the curve will extend into the negative region because it is fitted to the data, which *may* have come from a distribution where negative values are allowed. Choose a different distribution from `scipy.stats` (e.g. one that deals with strictly positive values) if you are looking for a different fit.

Comment: This is really helpful. Thanks.